# Android download and play video file simultaneously by using videoView

Tags: android

I had start download file and start playing that file. If the file size is small (less than 15 MB). Following source download and play video perfectly.
If the file size is big (50 MB or more than that),Video playing getting started. For my case,File size is 50 MB,downloaded size is 10 MB and video view is played when the download is started, once the 10 MB size video is played,It waiting for the upcoming bytes. When it gets downloaded, audio only get played. Video frame is not get updated.

```
public class VideoDemo extends Activity {

 private MediaController ctlr;

 VideoView videoView = null;

 Context context = null;
 long totalRead = 0;
 int bytesToRead = 50 * 1024;
 private int mPlayerPosition;
 private File mBufferFile;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
   super.onCreate(icicle);
   getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);


   videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview);


   ctlr = new MediaController(this);

   ctlr.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
   videoView.setMediaController(ctlr);
   videoView.requestFocus();

   new GetYoutubeFile().start();


  }



private class GetYoutubeFile extends Thread {
private String mUrl;
private String mFile;

public GetYoutubeFile() {

}

@Override
public void run() {
    super.run();
    try {

        File bufferingDir = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + "/YoutubeBuff");
        InputStream stream = getAssets().open("famous.3gp");
        if (stream == null)
            throw new RuntimeException("stream is null");
        File temp = File.createTempFile("test", "mp4");
        System.out.println("hi");
        temp.deleteOnExit();
        String tempPath = temp.getAbsolutePath();

        File bufferFile = File.createTempFile("test", "mp4");

        BufferedOutputStream bufferOS = new BufferedOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(bufferFile));


        InputStream is = getAssets().open("famous.3gp");
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is, 2048);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[16384];
        int numRead;
        boolean started = false;
        while ((numRead = bis.read(buffer)) != -1) {

            bufferOS.write(buffer, 0, numRead);
            bufferOS.flush();
            totalRead += numRead;
            if (totalRead > 120000 && !started) {
                Log.e("Player", "BufferHIT:StartPlay");
                setSourceAndStartPlay(bufferFile);
                started = true;
            }

        }
        mBufferFile = bufferFile;

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
}

public void setSourceAndStartPlay(File bufferFile) {
try {

    mPlayerPosition=videoView.getCurrentPosition();
    videoView.setVideoPath(bufferFile.getAbsolutePath());

    videoView.start();

} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
}

public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
 mPlayerPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
  try {
     mp.reset();
     videoView.setVideoPath(new File("mnt/sdcard/YoutubeBuff/"
            + mBufferFile).getAbsolutePath());
     mp.seekTo(mPlayerPosition);
     videoView.start();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Karthick

Your code seems ok!!
just register the OnCompletionListener,OnErrorListener to your VideoView.

```
 videoView.setOnCompletionListener(this);
 videoView.setOnErrorListener(this);
```

so once media player played the buffered stream it will goes to onCompletion or throws an error(Video Can't be played), Which can be handle by again changing seek position and playing through same buffered file.
(Please make sure that video bitrate and transfer rate needs to be equivalent) so buffering and streaming will run simultaneously.

implementations of methods could be like below,

```
@Override
public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mPlayerErrorPos = mp.getCurrentPosition();
    mPlayerPosition=mPlayerCompletionPos > mPlayerErrorPos ? mPlayerCompletionPos : mPlayerErrorPos;

    try {
        mp.reset();
        videoView.setVideoPath(video.getAbsolutePath());
        videoView.seekTo(mPlayerPosition);
        videoView.start();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    mPlayerCompletionPos = mp.getCurrentPosition();
  }
```